# Remove Realm from project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I don't need anymore Realm database in my project.
Entire project is about 750 megabytes because of realm.
How to remove Realm database from xCode project?

Comment: It really depends on how you added it your project. Carthage, cocoapods, SPM? Just follow the instructions for whichever one you used.

Comment: You can significantly reduce the size of any Realm project that contains by removing the unused SDK'S (tvOS for example). Our largest project comes in at 45Mb but we only have macOS components in the project. If your's is 750Mb, there's something else going on.